# Cannot set CONFIG_SFP

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm working with kernel V4.14.

There is a driver for SFPs in Linux. Config does not work however:

There is an entry in the makefile:

```
obj-$(CONFIG_SFP)       += sfp.o
```

There is also an entry in the `./drivers/net/phy/Kconfig`:

```
config SFP
    tristate "SFP cage support"
    depends on I2C && PHYLINK
    select MDIO_I2C
```

But with find (“/”) in menuconfig, I cannot find the config item.

Any clue why I cannot find this item?

I also cannot set PHYLINK

```
Symbol: PHYLINK [=n]
Type  : tristate
    Defined at drivers/net/phy/Kconfig:163
    Depends on: NETDEVICES [=y]
    Selects: PHYLIB [=y] && SWPHY [=y]
```

Comment: "_does not work_"? "_cannot find_"? Please elaborate with details.

Answer (score 2):

To enable `CONFIG_SFP`, starting from scratch on x86-64:

- select “General setup”

  - enable “Compile also drivers which will not load”
- select “Device drivers”

  - select “Network device support”

    - select “Ethernet driver support”

      - enable “Marvell Armada 370/38x/XP/37xx network interface support”
    - select “PHY Device support and infrastructure”

      - enable “SFP cage support”

You won’t find `PHYLINK` because it’s an invisible entry, automatically activated when necessary.

Comment: This is what  "--- PHY Device support and infrastructure"  looks like:      [ ]   Support LED triggers for tracking link state            
         *** MII PHY device drivers ***                          
   < >   AMD PHYs                                                
   < >   Aquantia PHYs
...

something like "SFP cage support" is simply missing.

Comment: I tried the following: removed dependency on PHYLINK in config SFP. Then I can select SFP in menuconfig.I greped entire kernel for PHYLINK: It is nowhere referenced except for the makefile and the kconfig. This cannot work.

Comment: Did you try the solution provided in my updated answer? You shouldn’t be modifying `Kconfig` files... (Your solution will allow you to select the option, but the module will probably fail to either build or load.)

Comment: Yes I just tried. CONFIG_MVNETA does "Selects: MVMDIO [=y] && FIXED_PHY [=y]  ". So it does not work. Really weired. I also see that phylink.c is not compiled

Comment: I agree I should not change Kconfig. This was just to isolate the cause.

Comment: Found out why it does not work in Kernel 4.14: CONFIG_MVNETA does "select FIXED_PHY". In 4.17 it does "select PHYLINK". So in 4.14 SFP cannot be selected.